# How to clear form data on leave - react native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, navigation

Im new to react native, and I can figurate how to clear a form.
I have a simpe app:
Home Screen with two bottons - Submit a ticket - Report accident. When you click of one of the buttons a new screen opens, when the user clicks submit takes back the user to the home page where they can select from the buttons again if the user selects Submit a ticket again all the previous data is pre-filled on the form is there a way to clear the form before it leaver the page.

This is the code that submits the data to the API:

```
const handleLogin = (data, setSubmitting) => {  
        const url = 'https://confirm.api';
     
        axios
            .post(url, data)
            .then((response) => {
            const result = response.data; 
            
            if (response.data == "Success") {
                navigation.navigate("Home");
            } else {
                handleMessage("There was an error please. Plese try again later.")
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            alert("Error");
        })
    }
```

My inputs look like this:

```
<MyTextInput
label           = "First Name" 
onChangeText    = {handleChange('first_name')}
onBlur          = {handleBlur('first_name')}
values          = {values.first_name}
returnKeyType   = "next"
onSubmitEditing = {() => input2.current.focus()}
/>
```

Comment: do you want to reset all input values in your form?

Comment: @Coder Yes, and start fresh

Comment: you can just set "" in your text Input values  while you navigate. just write a common method to set empty values and call it in your componentDidMount and navigate function.

Comment: still having problem just your entire file i can edit it for you